# Spring 4 Websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I am learning spring 4 websocket and i will be much thankful if anyone can guide me to learn spring 4 websocket step by step or can suggest some book where i can find step by step practical approach on the said subject.

But before that a little help needed here with this snippet that i am trying to execute on eclipse using tomcat 8 .

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello WebSocket</title>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/master/complete/src/main/resources/static/sockjs-0.3.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/master/complete/src/main/resources/static/stomp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stompClient = null;

    function setConnected(connected) {
        document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
        document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
        document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
    }

    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS("<c:url value='/hello'/>");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect('', '', function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe("<c:url value='/topic/greetings'/>", function(greeting){
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        stompClient.disconnect();
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    function sendName() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient.send("<c:url value='/app/hello'/>", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
    }

    function showGreeting(message) {
        var response = document.getElementById('response');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        response.appendChild(p);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websocket relies on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div>
<div>
    <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
    <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
</div>
<div id="conversationDiv">
    <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
    <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();">Send</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Greeting.java

```
public class Greeting {

private String content;

public Greeting(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

}
```

GreetingController.java

```
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
    System.out.println(message.getName());
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}

}
```

HelloMessage.java

```
package com.iiw.controller.relationship;

public class HelloMessage {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

WebsocketConfig.xml

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
   <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
   </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
   <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/WebSocketConfig.xml</param-value>

</context-param>
```

The Problem everytime i am running this code this is giving following error

```
    `Mar 21, 2015 9:00:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver] to required type [org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver' to required type 'org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver] to required type [org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:726)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`

I CHANGED THE

connect() function of html page to

```
 function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS("<c:url value='/hello'/>");
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            window.alert("Connected");
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                window.alert("Connected "+ frame);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
                });
            });
        }
```

this time alert box showing connected but not the later one is not showing up.

Comment: There is no yet any book on the matter. All info you can find in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html). Re. your issue: would you mind trying the same with the latest Spring [version](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)?

Comment: Its already been tried with the latest version of spring.

Comment: Well, show your dependencies, please. I can't reproduce with `4.1.5`

Comment: well Its not a maven project . so there's no pom.xml . but i added the following jars manually 1. spring-messaging-4.0.0.RELEASE , 2.spring-websocket-4.1.5.RELEASE. 3. spring-framework-4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: `spring-messaging` must be `4.1.5` too, as well as all other `spring-framework` modules. Be sure always use the same version for all modules!

Comment: I changed everything related to spring framework's version to 4.1.5. Now Its Running, there's no exception , index page is getting displayed . but nothing happens while clicking connect or send button.